# Can't render to texture on different hardware OpenGL

Tags: opengl, lwjgl

My friend and I are debugging our code on different computers.

My code is working while his is not. By process of elimination I determined the problem was that his system was not drawing to the custom frame buffer I use to render to a texture. The texture remained black.

Everything else is the same except for the system. Any advice here?

```
if(glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER) != GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE)
            throw new RuntimeException("yo frame buffer is broken);
```

this does not throw any exceptions so the frame buffer should be made correctly.

Comment: First thing I would do is check for errors. Call `glGetError` to check for general errors, and `glCheckFramebufferConsistency` to verify that the FBO was set up successfully.

Comment: I did both, none shed any light

Comment: are you sure it's not your window handling that could be causing the issue? e.g. while Using SFML I had issues seeing textures drawn to the screen because of my windows context settings

Comment: i can draw to the screen with the default frame buffer and a random texture not related to the other FBO's and it works.

Comment: Really hard to tell where the problem could be if it fails without any errors. Particularly without code, but there's probably nothing horribly wrong if it works on your machine. You say that the texture remains black. Is black your clear color? What if you use a different clear color for the FBO? Is it still black in the failure case, or is it the clear color?

Comment: @RetoKoradi Clearing does not work either, I can bind the frame, have color writing turned on, I can clear with any color and it will remain black. I believe the reason it's black is because it's initialized to all black.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_BASE_LEVEL, 0);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAX_LEVEL, 0);
```

I added these two lines for my color attachment texture and it worked.

Why does it work now? not completely sure why. GL was saying the FBO was complete even without having this

Comment: Odd. Probably a good idea to set MAX_LEVEL to 0 anyway if you're not planning to use mipmaps for the texture. But at least based on the information in this discussion, I don't understand why this should make a difference. Just out of curiosity, which platform showed the problem? I would certainly be interested as well if somebody has an explanation, beyond the possibility of a driver bug. One more suggested experiment, if you're up for it: Do you have to set MAX_LEVEL before rendering to the texture, or only before sampling from it?

Comment: It makes a difference because the default minification filter is `GL_NEAREST_MIPMAP_LINEAR` and that texture is mipmap incomplete if you do not call `glGenerateMipmap (...)`. Set the minification filter to `GL_NEAREST` or `GL_LINEAR` if you don't want to mipmap your FBO's image. Some drivers will actually generate a dummy mip-chain if you don't have one allocated but try to apply mipmap filtering, others will simply refuse to work. There is no behavior required by the GL specification when trying to mipmap filter a mipmap incomplete texture.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman: Yeah, that's why I was asking if he had to set MAX_LEVEL while rendering to the texture, or if it was only needed while sampling from the texture. If the answer was that it only makes a difference during sampling, the question about the minification filter was going to be next.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman I actually had             glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
            glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST); both, and this did not work alone, without adding the code above

Comment: @DanWebster: Are you using sampler objects by chance?